# Problem with software-properties-gtk in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt

I see

> Problem with software-properties-gtk in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

in the terminal when executing `software-properties-gtk`

I tried modifying the file **/etc/lsb-release** but this file is fine.

I have noticed that when you start, the file **/usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info** is overwritten blank, when I restore the Ubuntu. info file with the software-properties-gtk information it returns to function.

What could be the mistake? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to reinstall two packages - the Software & Updates itself and package with [*Ubuntu.info*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=Ubuntu.info&searchon=contents):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-gtk python-apt-common
```

and then retry.

Also I would recommend to check integrity of the whole system by using `debsums`.